# Power Automate Flow - Excel online date is in format DD-MM-YYYY but Sharepoint accept MM-DD-YYYY

Tags: power-automate

How can I fix my flow? I think it is throwing an error because sharepoint wants the MM-DD-YYYY format but my excel does not have it.

for example my online excel is cell will be "4-Sept-23" but read into SharePoint as April 9th 2023.

How can I fix this? Ive tried using `DateFormatTime` but getting error `The runtime value '"formatDateTime(15-05-2023, 'dd-MM-yyyy')"' to be converted doesn't have the expected format 'String/date'.`
This date is actually May 15th 2023 in my excel but sharepoint obviously will throw an error because there is no 15th month.

How do I combat this?

My flow:

[image]

compose 1:

`trim(items('Apply_to_each_2')?['Usethis'])`

Compose 2:

`trim(addDays('1899-12-30',int(outputs('Compose')),'dd-MM-yyyy'))`

sample data:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- I am considering you will get value from excel in following format '04-09-2023' and want to convert in '09-04-2023'
- follow the below steps for converting it.
- declare a variable of type string and pass the value as `utcNow('04-09-2023')`
  [image]
- create compose action from data operation connector and pass the value as below

```
split(variables('DATE'),'-')
```

[image]

- finally concatenate the string using below method

```
concat(outputs('Compose')[1],'-',outputs('Compose')[0],'-',outputs('Compose')[2])
```

[image]

- you will get the desired output.

[image]
[image]
[image]